# How to create route link in list using javascript or vue js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router

How to create route link in list like below? When we click on route link it will save route name and show it in list in the page and we click on another route link it will append the route name to list in the page. How to create like this?

Example: Home/users/user-list/create

note: when we click on user-list it we redirect to user list page again

Comment: Are you by any chance using vuetify or any bootstrap-like framework in your project?

Comment: What you are describing is commonly called "breadcrumbs". Just google "vue router breadcrumbs" and you will get lots of useful tutorials and examples...

Comment: Oh you make sense yeah that's true I just don't know how to call it that's why I make common question now I got it thank you so much.